# Turning an xsl:for-each in a single XPath expression

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'd like to filter the collection of elements (menu items).
I did it by for-each. It looks like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="actualMenus">
 <xsl:for-each select="$menus">
  <xsl:variable name ="startDate" select="current()/cs:Properties/cs:CommercePropertyItem[cs:Key='StartDate']/cs:Value"/>
  <xsl:variable name ="endDate" select="current()/cs:Properties/cs:CommercePropertyItem[cs:Key='EndDate']/cs:Value"/>
  <xsl:variable name="today" select="translate(substring-before($menuDate, 'T'), '-', '')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="start" select="translate(substring-before($startDate, 'T'), '-', '')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="end" select="translate(substring-before($endDate, 'T'), '-', '')"/>

  <xsl:if test="$start &lt;= $today and $today &lt;= $end">
    <child>
      <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </child>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

And then I use it by following code:
    `msxsl:node-set($actualMenus)/child`

I try to replace code above with xpath expression:

```
<xsl:variable name="actualMenus" 
     select="$menus[translate(substring-before(current()/cs:Properties/cs:CommercePropertyItem[cs:Key='StartDate']/cs:Value, 'T'), '-', '') &lt;= translate(substring-before($menuDate, 'T'), '-', '') 
                and translate(substring-before($menuDate, 'T'), '-', '') &lt;= translate(substring-before(current()/cs:Properties/cs:CommercePropertyItem[cs:Key='EndDate']/cs:Value, 'T'), '-', '')]" />
```

Unfortunatelly, It doesn't work.

Could someone help me to find out mistakes in xpath expression ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What did it actually do and how is that different from what you required?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think what you are trying to ask is how to go from the `for-each` to a single-line XPath and you have trouble getting it right. For us to help you with it, we will need the input XML and the context (i.e., is the variable in the root, or in a template?). Please update with a minimal fully working XML input and XSLT stylesheet that illustrates your problem, otherwise it is nothing more than a guessing game for us. See also [ask].

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'd like to go from the `for-each` to a single-line XPath expression. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you didn't show the context (see my comment above, please update your question). However, my guess is that the issue lies with `current()`. In your `xsl:for-each`, the `current`-function points to the current node the for-each is processing. In your new select-expression, the `current`-function points to whatever is the context node *outside* the XPath expression. It *does not* point to the current item in `$menus`, you should use the context item expression `.` for that (though in your case it is redundant).

I tried your code by adding what seemed to be a possible input document (again, please update your question with it!). If you run the following stylesheet, it outputs the same for both `xsl:value-of` instructions. You can run the stylesheet against any input document, it will just take the variable `$menus` (I wrapped it in a `node-set`).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cs="http://whatever/cs"
    xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ext cs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="menuDate" select="'2014-08-14T03:44'" />
    <xsl:variable name="menus" >
        <cs:Properties>
            <cs:CommercePropertyItem>
                <cs:Key>StartDate</cs:Key>
                <cs:Value>2014-03-04T12:38</cs:Value>
            </cs:CommercePropertyItem>
            <cs:CommercePropertyItem>
                <cs:Key>EndDate</cs:Key>
                <cs:Value>2014-12-04T12:38</cs:Value>
            </cs:CommercePropertyItem>
        </cs:Properties>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:variable name="actualMenus">
            <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($menus)">
                <xsl:variable name ="startDate" select="current()/cs:Properties/cs:CommercePropertyItem[cs:Key='StartDate']/cs:Value"/>
                <xsl:variable name ="endDate" select="current()/cs:Properties/cs:CommercePropertyItem[cs:Key='EndDate']/cs:Value"/>
                <xsl:variable name="today" select="translate(substring-before($menuDate, 'T'), '-', '')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="start" select="translate(substring-before($startDate, 'T'), '-', '')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="end" select="translate(substring-before($endDate, 'T'), '-', '')"/>

                <xsl:if test="$start &lt;= $today and $today &lt;= $end">
                    <child>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                    </child>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- output text value of actual menu -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$actualMenus" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <!-- output text value of actual menu using single XPath -->
        <xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($menus)
            [
                translate(substring-before(cs:Properties/cs:CommercePropertyItem[cs:Key='StartDate']/cs:Value, 'T'), '-', '') 
                &lt;= translate(substring-before($menuDate, 'T'), '-', '') 
                and 
                translate(substring-before($menuDate, 'T'), '-', '') 
                &lt;= translate(substring-before(cs:Properties/cs:CommercePropertyItem[cs:Key='EndDate']/cs:Value, 'T'), '-', '')
            ]" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will output:

```
StartDate2014-03-04T12:38EndDate2014-12-04T12:38
StartDate2014-03-04T12:38EndDate2014-12-04T12:38
```

The difference between your expression and mine is that I remove the `current()` from your expression. Which, as it turns out, is also redundant in your for-each loop, as the node that takes the focus by default is the same as the one returned by `current()` (but don't forget to remove the leading slash).

I am not sure *why* you want it to be a one-liner XPath. I don't think the code becomes clearer that way, but of course, that is a matter of taste.